# Building cordova apps in 2017 occurs MSBuild Error

Tags: cordova, angular7

I have an **Angular & Cordova** project, It works smoothly in browser (*Angular*) but anytime I try to get *Mobile Package* and build *Cordova Project* it occurs an error like below.

Error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed
>   with exit code 1  MyProject.Mobile

I've tried this in 4 other computers.The result is same.It's been 3 three days i am trying to resolve this but I cant.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your path

```
set path=%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin
```

Let me know if its working or not.

Comment: I didn't tried this but i've find out what is wrong.The reason was my project path is too longer for MSBuild. Then I've just copy my project in diffrent location and build it with cordova cli